coverage.py with multiprocessing only works with unittest but not with pytest?
I'm trying to track the coverage of testing python code with coverage.py. Some tests spawn subprocesses using multiprocessing, so following the documentation for coverage.py I'm using a configuration file with:
[run]
parallel=true
concurrency=multiprocessing

Let's consider the following snippet as a minimal testing example:
import logging
import unittest
import multiprocessing


def some_func():
    logging.info('this is')
    logging.info('just a test')


class TestSomefunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_reporting(self):
        rf = multiprocessing.Process(target=some_func)
        rf.start()
        rf.join()


Now running this with coverage run -m unittest test_coverage.py && coverage combine && coverage report gives the expected results, i.e. all lines of the file are covered.
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.014s

OK
Combined data file .coverage.k.26272.XjRmpvHx
Combined data file .coverage.k.26274.XLxuiHUx
Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------
__init__.py                        0      0   100%
test_coverage.py                  11      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                             11      0   100%

Now let's take essentially the same code as if it was pytest instead of unittest:
import logging
import multiprocessing


def some_func():
    logging.info('this is')
    logging.info('just a test')


def test_reporting():
    rf = multiprocessing.Process(target=some_func)
    rf.start()
    rf.join()


running coverage run -m pytest test_coverage_pytest.py && coverage combine && coverage report does not account for the lines hit by the subprocess:
Combined data file .coverage.k.26411.XWRtKBux
Name                                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__init__.py                                                          0      0   100%
test_coverage_pytest.py                                              9      2    78%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                                9      2      %

in that case coverage.py only produces a single coverage file, as opposed to the unittest execution which produces files from both processes.
So my question then is: what am I doing wrong not to get the expected results with pytest. Is there another configuration that needs to be set? Does coverage run need to be called in a different way? I just can't seem to get it to work, any help is much appreciated.
